# separating hyperlinks in webpage footer

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I added a footer that has a link to my GitHub profile and the website repo. I've got the footer looking how I want it to except the links are right next to each other with barley any space between them. I've tried to add a paragraph with just spaces in between the links but then it made the footer just have three separate lines. How can I add some space between the links and keep them on the same line.

Here is the CSS and HTML for my footer:

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: DarkGray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
 <a href="[github profile url]">GitHub Profile</a>
 <a href="[website repo link]">Website Repo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually separate elements like that by making a class to pad the items in question. Adding padding to elements can space them out. You can change the element's placement in its parent element with various "`display`" settings, or use `margin` or even `border` to put space between things, or even use `columns` in the space provided, but padding seems to be the most appropriate use.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: DarkGray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.footer-links {
 padding: 0 10px 0 10px; /* padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom, padding-left */
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
 <a class="footer-links" href="[github profile url]">GitHub Profile</a> /* add this class to each of your footer items */
 <a class="footer-links" href="[website repo link]">Website Repo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achieve spacing between the links using the `padding` property. For example: put on the links classes with the same name:

```
<div class="footer">
 <a href="[github profile url]" class="footer__link">GitHub Profile</a>
 <a href="[website repo link]" class="footer__link">Website Repo</a>
</div>
```

and then in CSS:

```
.footer__link {
    padding-right: (your value --> it could be in px,em,rem etc.);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For situations like the this, I like to use flexbox. I've added the justify option to space-around in this case but there are many more options. See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp for more info:

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: DarkGray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <a href="[github profile url]">GitHub Profile</a>
  <a href="[website repo link]">Website Repo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use margin in your css like this:

```
.footer a:first-child{
  margin-right: 50px(change to how much you want);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding or margin on both sides of the anchor tag.

````
.footer a {
   padding: 0 10px; /**Or whatever value you want**/
}

/**OR**/

.footer a {
   margin: 0 10px; /**Or whatever value you want**/
}
```
````